# one liner shell command for changing file creation date in windows

Tags: file, winapi, shell, date, command

After hours of searching on the internet, I still have not come across any one liner command that could change the file creation date in windows. I know there are Win32 APIs that can do the job. I dont need third party utilites. I need a single command that could be executed in the windows shell to do the job. I would eventually be opening the windows shell from Java to execute this.

Comment: Why not just do it natively from Java, or create your own small shell executable that you can call "on one line" from Java?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way you can do it in Java. There is no API support except for changing the last modified date.

Answer (score 1):

There is no (native) command line program to change the creation time of a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Subsystem for Linux you can do it in two commands:

1. `wsl`
2. `touch [file]`